# Chip and Chirp rate in LoRa

Tags: lora

I'm a bit confused with LoRa. I understand the CSS modulation with the chirps, but I don't get what chips are. Are chips parts of the chirps?
I saw another topic on this, but the difference is not clear. As I understand it now, is that chirps consist of chirps. Is that correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS modulation uses "chirps" to spread the spectrum (i.e. the signal's center frequency increases during the entire transmission, while bandwidth remains constant).

In contrast, CDMA systems use "[chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_(CDMA))" to spread out the signal. Here, the center frequency remains constant, but bandwidth of the transmitted signal around the center increases, and different chip sequences can be used to separate channels.

Comment: So a chip has nothing to do with LoRa?

Comment: It's not that easy. LoRa indeed uses chip sequences, consisting of chirps. So, you need to understand spread spectrum technologies and what a chirp is.